# como actualizar el texto de un radiobutton en tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

hola tengo el siguiente codigo que pretedo actualize el texto del radiobutton al oprimir el boton y que contiene la funcion de recorrer la base de datos de sqlite y pasar el valor a la variables `row1` y que ese valor se coloque en el radio button este es mi codigo:

```
from tkinter import Tk,Radiobutton,Button,Label,Toplevel
import sqlite3

ventana = Tk()

def getData():
    conexion = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
    cursor = conexion.cursor()
    s = cursor.execute("SELECT id,pregunta1,pregunta2,pregunta3 FROM Tabla1 WHERE id=1")
    for i in s:
        print(i[1])
        row1=i[1]

row1 = "None"
Radiobutton(ventana,text=row1).place(x=320,y=190)
pushbutton = Button(ventana,text="oprime",command=getData).place(x=320,y=220)


ventana.geometry("800x600")
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sin tocar mucho lo que tenes y reemplazando la recuperación de la base con una asignación. Este ejemplo cambia el label

```
from tkinter import Tk,Radiobutton,Button,Label,Toplevel
ventana = Tk()

def getData():
      dato="Hoy es un dia soleado"
      boton.configure(text=dato)

row1 = "None"
boton=Radiobutton(ventana,text=row1)
boton.place(x=320,y=190)
pushbutton = Button(ventana,text="oprime",command=getData).place(x=320,y=220)
ventana.geometry("800x600")
ventana.mainloop()
```

Antes del click

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues del click

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos